# How to plot a histogram in matplotlib in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I know how to plot a histogram when individual datapoints are given like:
(33, 45, 54, 33, 21, 29, 15, ...)

by simply using something `matplotlib.pyplot.hist(x, bins=10)`

but what if I only have grouped data like:

[image: | Marks |Number of students | | -------- | ----------------- | | 0-10 | 8 | | 10-20 | 12 | | 20-30 | 24 | | 30-40 | 26 | | ...... | ...... |]
and so on.

I know that I can use bar plots to mimic a histogram by changing `xticks` but what if I want to do this by using only `hist` function of `matplotlib.pyplot`?

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: The table formatting was not working properly so I used an image instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the `hist()` params manually and use the existing value counts as `weights`.

Say you have this `df`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Marks': ['0-10', '10-20', '20-30', '30-40'], 'Number of students': [8, 12, 24, 26]})
   Marks  Number of students
0   0-10                   8
1  10-20                  12
2  20-30                  24
3  30-40                  26
```

The `bins` are all the unique boundary values in `Marks`:

```py
>>> bins = pd.unique(df.Marks.str.split('-', expand=True).astype(int).values.ravel())
array([ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40])
```

Choose one `x` value per bin, e.g. the left edge to make it easy:

```py
>>> x = bins[:-1]
array([ 0, 10, 20, 30])
```

Use the existing value counts (`Number of students`) as `weights`:

```py
>>> weights = df['Number of students'].values
array([ 8, 12, 24, 26])
```

Then plug these into `hist()`:

```py
>>> plt.hist(x=x, bins=bins, weights=weights)
```

[image: reconstructed histogram]

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to “ungroup” data yourself.

For example, for the 8 students with a mark between 0 and 10, you can generate 8 data points of value of 5 (the mean). For the 12 with a mark between 10 and 20, you can generate 12 data points of value 15.

However, the “ungrouped” data will only be an approximation of the real data. Thus, it is probably better to just use a `matplotlib.pyplot.bar` plot.